# How to make a div appear on hover of another div (CSS or JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, css, html, hover

I did a lot of searching but none of these solutions are working for me.

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HS3jh/

I need my `ABOUTTAB` div to be visible when you hover over the tab `tab2`.

```
#ABOUTTAB {
  position: absolute;
  width: 218px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-top: -32px;
  margin-left: 231px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Feel free to do it with CSS or Javascript, thanks for any help, even mess around with the html if you need to.

Comment: You should look into drop downs from [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns)

Comment: Your markup has `<center>` tags in it. It's 2014. Stop that!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it fairly easily with some jQuery. Something to the effect of

```
$('#tab2').hover(
    function(){
        $('#ABOUTTAB').show();
    },
    function(){
        $('#ABOUTTAB').hide();
    });
```

The first function passed to hover() is the onMouseEnter handler, and the second is the onMouseExit handler. So you when you hover tab2, ABOUTTAB is displayed, and when you unhover it's hidden. Start it as `display:none` to hide it.

Do some research into jQuery. This sort of DOM manipulation is very simple and intuitive with it.

Comment: Although this might work, the OP didn't explicitly mention the usage of jQuery. He might or might not need it, which is why I gave a plain JS solution (a bit more verbose).

Answer (score 0):

Using pure JavaScript, that can be achieved with something similar to:

```
document.querySelector("#tab2").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  document.querySelector("#ABOUTTAB").style.visibility = "visible";
});

document.querySelector("#tab2").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  document.querySelector("#ABOUTTAB").style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```

That way, you don't need jQuery [but if you need it to work with IE < 8](http://caniuse.com/queryselector), user `getElementById` instead of `querySelector` (and don't forget to remove the `#`, which is the `id` selector).

Answer (score 0):

this is an option

on JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function wait(){
    var tab2 =  document.getElementById("tab2");
    tab2.addEventListener('mouseover',change,false);

}


function change(){
    document.getElementById('ABOUTTAB').style.visibility =  "visible";
}


</script>
```

in this example don't change to hidden.

and this on the body

```
<body onload="wait()">
```

when the browser load webpage charge the function.